# How to make a:hover work with content wrappers?

Tags: html, css, hover, wrapper

I'm having trouble with content wrappers as they are preventing my hover interactions from working.
The goal is to get the div with class='card' to have an interaction when the mouse goes over it.

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card>div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card .foreground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background-color: blue;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.card:hover .foreground {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class='foreground'> </div>
  <div class='background'> </div>
</div>
```

All info here:
https://codepen.io/kaijinny/pen/poWezRL

Answer (score 1):

Since the element with the class `.section-bubble1`
has a `z-index: -1`, it is not available for hover (because it is "under" the layer).
You need to reconsider the order of the `z-index`.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg. I was looking at my CSS for ages and missed it.